# "Process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process"

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel, streamreader, data-import

I need to upload a CSV file to an ASP.NET application, on an Azure server. Although it works fine on my local machine, when uploading it to the server the following error is thrown:

> "Process cannot access the file
>   'C:\inetpub\wwwroot\ImportFiles\9_11.csv' because it is being used by
>   another process"

My code:

```
        string fileName = DateTime.Now.ToString().Replace(':', '_').Replace('/', '_').Replace(' ', '_') + Convert.ToString((new Random()).Next(0, 999) * (new Random()).Next(0, 999));
        string path = Server.MapPath("ImportFiles") + "\\" + fileName + "" + FileImport.FileName.Substring(FileImport.FileName.IndexOf('.'));
        FileImport.SaveAs(path);
        string pathforSeconStream = path;
        try
        {
            Response.Write("<script> alert('In Try Block');</script>");
            bool flag = true;
            int visiblemessageCount = 0;
            int rollNo = 1;
            StreamReader ColLine = new StreamReader(path);
            string ColInputline = ColLine.ReadLine();
            String[] ColsInput = ColInputline.Split(',');
            ColLine.Close();
            ColLine.Dispose();
            string preFix = "", RollNumber = "";
            StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(pathforSeconStream);
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The code to generate a unique filename is wrong.  Use [Path.GetTempFileName](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.gettempfilename(v=vs.110).aspx).

**PS** never eat an exceptiion. Please remove `catch (Exception ex) {}`;

**Revision**

Instead of `FileImport.Save(...)` just save the request in a [MemoryStream](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.memorystream(v=vs.110).aspx) and then work on it.

Comment: thanks, 
But I need to save that file in two stream objects for further processing.First I save stream in object "ColLine" and second I save stream in "sr" object..but it through error message although it works perfectly on my dev machine.

Comment: @Shahab the code you have shown does nothing in the `try` block.  If the there is more code that you have not shown you can always reset the current position of the `MemoryStream`.

Comment: There is lot of code that I could not past that made my question use less no one want to read a lot of code by the way there is one queries that execute after matching two array list values.